# Error C++ 2679 (binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

**HI. Before my question, I've looked in other threads with same error, nothing worked for me.** 
My problem code is at `in >> a.name >> a.extension;`. As I tested myself, if I change the type from `string` to `char` for my variables, it will work, but I can't make it work with a `string` type of value.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Below full error code on compillation (Visual Studio 2015)

> Error C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Soft {
private:
    int *size;
    time_t *dateTime;
public:
    string name;
    string extension;
    Soft();
    Soft(string, string);
    Soft(const Soft&source);
    ~Soft();

    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const Soft& a) 
    {
        in >> a.name >> a.extension;
        return in;
    };

    void changeName(string);
    void changeExtension(string);
};

Soft::Soft() {
    size = new int;
    *size = 0;
    name = string("");
    extension = string("");
    dateTime = new time_t;
    *dateTime = time(nullptr);
}

Soft::Soft(const Soft&source) {
    name = source.name;
    extension = source.extension;
    size = new int;
    *size = *source.size;
    dateTime = new time_t;
    *dateTime = time(nullptr);
}

Soft::Soft(string a, string b) {
    name = a;
    extension = b;
    dateTime = new time_t;
    *dateTime = time(nullptr);
}

Soft::~Soft() {
    delete[] size;
    delete[] dateTime;
}

void Soft::changeExtension(string a) {
    extension = a;
}
void Soft::changeName(string a) {
    name = a;
}


int main() {

    Soft a;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word here is `const`, which means that the thing cannot be modified.

**You are trying to modify a `const` thing. You cannot do that.**

Your function, like any `operator>>` in general, should be declared like this:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Soft& a)
```

The change I have made is to remove the `const`.

By the way, I see no reason at all for your member variables `size` and `dateTime` to be pointers to dynamically allocated integers. Your code will be *much simpler* if you just make them normal integers.

Comment: I don't see either, but my school teacher wants everything with pointers... It's written explicitly to use pointers for all variables

Comment: @M.Eugen: That's ludicrous. You are being taught how to do it wrong. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: haven't you been taught what 'mutable' keyword does?? he can declare his member data as mutable and then his example will work fine

Comment: @Raindrop7: Why would he do that? Just declare the operator correctly... it makes no sense to take a `const` reference to an object into a function whose sole purpose is to mutate that object.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the answer is below I said you can even being silly. but I didn't advise him to do so

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator's l-Value mustn't be constant because this operator changes the values so trying to change a constant value is a trying to break the rules.

look at insertion operator:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const myCalss&); // here const is ok
```

here it's ok because the insertion operator is just used to print values (const and non-const) without changing them.

*** if your really need to Break the rules of constness declare your member data as mutable:

```
     mutable int *size;
     mutable time_t *dateTime;
```

but in your example you needn't to do so, I just explain that you can change cont variable.